# Trouble with IIS Fileshare access from machine on one domain across vpn to machine on another domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, domain

We have two machines, Server A and Server B.

Server A is on a domain and hosts a web page that our employees use to access some basic information (no sign on needed, open to all employees).

Server A needs to access information from Server B.

Server B sits on a separate domain, across a VPN. The VPN is always connected, and the website is successfully able to connect to a SQL database across that connection using a connection string (and an SA account).

The problem comes when we need to read information from files on Server B from Server A. Unsure how to pass domain credentials when an anonymous user accesses the webpage so that it can access those files each time.

We have also tried setting up a local account on each machine with the same password, and still can't seem to successfully access the shares.

TL;DR what's the easiest way to allow IIS to access files on a computer from another domain?

Comment: so much wrong to little time, but from server A to server B it should prompt you for creds if anything is configured half way correctly (I almost assume not) when it does you need to enter for the username B\username username being a local account on B.

Comment: Admittedly I don't work with IIS very much but if you're using Anonymous access on the web site on server B then I believe your IUSR account on server B needs Read and List Folder Contents NTFS permissions on the folder where the files reside.